# Creating an alias in solaris unix

Tags: unix, solaris, command-line-arguments, alias

I can create an alias in solaris as below:

```
alias x86 "some_command"
```

I need something that i can pass an argument to an alias and that argument will be used to frame the complete alias.
for example:

there is a command like :

```
ct setview 1.0_myname
```

and for the above i write the alias as

```
alias sv "ct setview 1.0_myname"
```

in the above command 1.0 is the version and it can keep changing.

so what i want is to create an alias like :

```
alias sv "ct steview $1_myname"#well i donno whether this is correct
```

and i want to use this alias as 
`sv 1.0` or `sv 2.0`

Comment: What shell are you using ? I think alias is a feature of the shell, not of the OS.

Comment: i have tcsh in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash (or equivalent shell), the alias function cannot transmit arguments. Instead, you can create a function :

```
sv() { ct "setview $@_myname" ;}
```

And use it like an alias (sv 1.0)

*Depending on your config you may need to provide full path of the **ct** binary*

Comment: Could you please eloberate on the usage?May be with an example!

Comment: I did provide an example. Use : `sv 1.0`

Answer (score 0):

For csh & tcsh shells, there's limited argument substitution in aliases, using ! syntax,
such as:

```
 alias sv 'ct steview \!:1_myname'
```

More details and examples at:

- [Writing Aliases in csh and tcsh](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html)
- [Online Unix Help: C Shell: Aliases](http://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/aliases.html)